# Default call to UITableViewDataSource/Delegate methods

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have added a table view to a view controller but haven't connected the data source and delegate to that view controller. So in that case is there any default implementation of those required methods (of `UITableViewDataSource`/`Delegate`) that gets called? The program is not crashing and not showing any data as well.

Comment: do you mean connect them via code ?

Comment: use tableViewController instead of viewController but you must have to implement its delegate method of it ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `UITableView` with no delegate and no data source will simply show an empty table. It won't crash but it's useless since you don't provide any data.

By default a table view shows one section with zero rows. That is why it doesn't crash. If you read the documentation for `UITableViewDataSource` you will see that `numberOfSectionsInTableView:` has a default value of 1. Without a data source, the table assumes 0 rows for the section.

Many of the `UITableViewDelegate` methods also assume an appropriate default value.

Comment: @rmaddy-Where can I find this default initalization.I mean in which class it is implemented?

Comment: It's built into `UITableView`. There's nothing to see. It's just how it works.